# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry runs away

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Looking for a *Harry Potter* fan-fic where Harry runs away.

He tries to go to Hermione's but Snape shows up and it turns out that Snape is Harry's dad. Snape lives with Lucius as his head of family. Draco does not want to believe Harry is Snape's son; he calls Harry "scar head" and pushes him after Harry tells Draco what Draco's runespore said about him. Harry's accidental magic acts up and he grows a tree in the snake atrium. The snakes in the atrium room all belong to Draco.

He begs the adults not to punish them, and he puts up a shield wandlessly. Harry is an elemental emp or elf, maybe a Veela. There is spanking in this story; Draco's mom punishes Draco for his bad behaviour with a magical hair brush (it is not really magical she just tells him that so his pride is not hurt). Harry was abused by the Dursleys that is why he ran away. Harry has a flashback when Draco called him a freak, that is why his magic acted up; Harry has scars and Draco sees them.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example do you know when you read this?

Comment: Hi there. I've taken the liberty to edit your question; you can rollback if you think it changes its meaning. In particular, something was unclear in your first draft: Harry is Snape's son, right? Not the other way around? (this would be mathematically weird) Other than that, could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your post? For instance, where did you read that? ArchiveofOurOwn? Fanfiction.net? When was it?

Comment: This reminds me a bit of https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12606953/1/Slytherin-Adoption but the first chapter doesn't seem to match.

Comment: it's not slytherin adoption but thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I found it! "[An Unexpected Surprise](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10665728/1/An-Unexpected-Surprise)" by TRUMAN'S SHELL

> *He took Severus away from his son and me. Yes Remus, Harry is Severus' son. I used a stasis spell two weeks after Severus left me. Did you never wonder why I married James so quickly? You knew my love for Severus was true. Yes I loved James, but that love was always as a friend.*

....

> "It appears Harry has runaway from home. Would you please find him?"

....

> "So Lord Malfoy is your father, now?"
>   "No, I consider him to be my older brother, but he does have the right to control my inheritance like a parent does. He also is the Head of our family," Severus said with a smile.

....

> "I'm not fucking jealous of Potter!" Draco screeched angrily. "He's a scar headed orphan, who hangs out with mudbloods, and blood traitors! He's a bloody Gryffindor! Dumbledore's puppet! He isn't worth anything, let alone my bloody jealousy!"

....

> "Ah used your so called magic hairbrush?" Lucius said knowingly.
>   "Yes and since I used a brush, I hope you won't spank him again."

....

> A beautiful oleander tree standing in the middle of the atrium was a dead give away of who lost control of their magic. Lucius didn't have to be a seer to know that Draco's mouth had led to Harry's accidental magic. What did surprise the patriarch of the Malfoy family was seeing Harry in a ball sobbing on Draco's lap and that his son was running his fingers through the younger boy's hair, whispering soft words in the boy's ear.

Comment: Thanks for telling us what this is, you should be able to accept your own answer in approximately 47 hours. Please come back and do so!

Comment: In addition to what TheLethalCarrot said, if you could provide some quotes from the fanfic which matched what you remembered and edit them into your answer, that would be great! This way, people looking for the same fanfic might be able to find it there! :)